# Jetpack Compose lifecycle-viewmodel dependecy makes random() from collection not random

Tags: build.gradle, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I noticed very strange behavior how the random() from any collection is working after I added dependency  "implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.5.1"" in my project.
After addition of dependency all calling random() from any collection gives me the same set of results.
For example the following code will always give me the same numbers. I start the app. Making some taps on the text and see some set of numbers. Close the app and clear it from memory start again and see the same set of number. Even after re-installation I see the same set of numbers

```
var numbers by remember {
    mutableStateOf("numbersFromSet")
}
Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
    val setOfNumbers = setOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    Text(text = numbers, modifier = Modifier.clickable {
        numbers = setOfNumbers.random().toString()
    })
}
```

It doesn't matter what collection I am using and where it's stored. It looks like after addition of the dependency the output of random() became predefined. I can see such behavior on the physical and virtual devices. After deletion of the dependency from gradle the random() is strating to work as expected. I always see the random results.
I am using android studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 1 if it's matter
I will be very grateful for any answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your problem, you can use below solution to get different numbers every time.
It is just changing the `seed` for the `Random` every time you click.

```
numbers = setOfNumbers.random(Random(System.currentTimeMillis())).toString()
```

For the reason why Kotlin `Random` is giving the same numbers is because it uses the same `seed`, more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74472655/4192614) and [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random.html).
I am not sure why this happens only with that specific dependency though. However the above solution will work when using that dependency too as the `seed` is unique.