# android random keeps generating the same int sequence

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm having a well known problem in android which is generating random numbers. the problem is that i need to generate 20 random numbers between 1 and 905 every time a screen is loaded. and if i use kotlin random it keeps generating the same sequence even if i'm closing and reopen the app. and java random and secure random generates different sequence only if i'm closing and reopening the app. but i want to have different sequences even if i dont close the app and open it again.
i know it has been asked before but my problem is that i tried every solution and its the same results.
i would appreciate the help if anyone knows what the hell is wrong.

here are the solutions i used:

1.

```
val randomIndex: List<Int> = List(20){
    java.util.Random().nextInt(905) + 1
}
```

2. 

```
val randomIndex: MutableSet<Int> = remember{ mutableSetOf() }

while (randomIndex.size < 20){
    randomIndex.add(java.util.Random().nextInt(905) + 1)
}
```

3. 

```
val randomIndex: List<Int> = (0..905).toList.shuffled(Random).subList(0,20)
```

i'm using jetpack compose and kotlin so ignore all the mutable state and remembers. also where ever you see `Random` i used all java `Random`, `SecureRandom` and kotlin `Random` and the problem i discussed persists.
i also tried initializing `Random` out of loop on the second code i put here and still it does the same thing.

**EDIT**:
thought i mentioned these here aswell. i'm using kolin 1.6.10 and my compile sdk for android is 33. i'm also trying the app on 2 different phones with android 8 and 11.

**EDIT2**:
@Tenfout04 suggested to put my indexes outside of my composable so this is what i did inside of my viewmodel:

```
var pokemonIndex: List<Int> = mutableStateListOf()

init {
    pokemonIndex = List(20){
        java.util.Random().nextInt(905)+1
    }
}
```

and in my composable:

```
val viewModel: PokemonGameViewModel = hiltViewModel()
val randomIndex = viewModel.pokemonIndex
```

another thing i tried in my viewmodel is:

```
val pokemonIndex: MutableState<List<Int>>
get() = mutableStateOf(
    List(20){
        java.util.Random().nextInt(905)+1
    }
)
```

results are the same :(

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73475522/kotlin-random-always-generates-the-same-random-numbers

Comment: @khashayaramini hey thanks for the comment but i tried that. see the problem is that in that case they closed and reopened the app in order to have a different sequence generated. but my problem is that i dont want to close it in order to have a different sequence

Comment: Are you using Kotlin 1.7.10 or lower? There's a bug in Android that can cause this issue, and Kotlin 1.7.20 is modified to work around the Android bug. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52618/ThreadLocalRandom-is-not-a-good-source-of-randomness-on-Android-before-SDK-34-so-dont-use-it-for-Kotlin-Random

Comment: @Tenfour04 well even if the problem is with kotlin's wouldn't it be fixed with just using java random instead?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I would expect it to work when directly calling `java.util.Random()`, yes. Could be something else then, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yeah well `java.util.Random` and `java.security.SecureRandom` they kinda work. see if i close the app and re open it gives me different sequence but i want it to happen without closing the app and just with reloading the screen.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you said that in your question already and I missed that detail. I think it will have to do with which event(s) you want to trigger the creation of a new list. You need to use `remember` so the list isn't changed every time there's a recomposition, but you want to change the value under certain events. So I think you should have the list of randoms in a MutableState, and under certain conditions recreate the list in the MutableState. You might need to lift it out of your Composable or base it off some Flow trigger in the view model so you can trigger the refresh from anywhere.

Comment: @Tenfour04 i am using mutable state and remember but if i put my list outside of my composable i can not use remember anymore since it needs to be declared inside of a composable. but i am initializing my list outside of any component so even before making my components i am initializing list. and that happens only when im loading the screen fresh. but still let me know if i haven't fully understood your comment.

Comment: @Tenfour04 and about doing it in view modelbased of flow i can do that but i think it just adds more unnecessary operations to a simple task of getting 20 random numbers

Comment: If you lift it out (maybe put it in a ViewModel), then you don't need to remember it because the ViewModel outlives the composition. The reason I suggest lifting it out is so you can call some function that refreshes the list under certain events, which I think is the use case you are describing you need.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yeah true i then i dont need the remember and i can just put it in side of my mutable state and everytime on loading the screen initilize it again, but wouldn't it be the same? i mean i can try.

Comment: It should be different each time you re-initialize the list inisde the state, provided you are using a Random that has a random seed, which should be the case if you use `java.util.Random` (or Kotlin Random if using Kotlin 1.7.20).

Comment: @Tenfour04 i updated the question so now i'm doing that and stillthe results are the same

Comment: The other half of what I suggested is that you reinitialize the list on some event. Whatever event you want to trigger it to be a new list. It's not going to happen automatically. You have to do it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 well on initializing the viewmodel or getting the list from viewmodel it is going to initilize the list again which the event is opening the screen and on loading the screen getting the list or making the viewmodel

Comment: my event has to be on screen load which is when you navigate to the screen and get the variable you want. right?

Comment: you know i think theproblem is that the java random is not meant to create different sequences on one run in android which is a big problem. i dont know if that is true but i think thats the problem

Comment: That's not true. The only way to get a Random to generate the same thing again is to be using a specific seed value when you initialize it. I guess I don't have a clear picture of when you want a new list and when you don't. You described that it worked ok when closing and reopening the screen. Now you say you want a new list when the screen is loaded, which sounds like the same thing, so the problem should already be resolved?

Comment: so the app is a having multiple comosable screens which are handled on with compose navigation on a single activity. now one of the screens is this screen that upon loading has to make a list of 20 random numbers. so whenever i close the app random is working but with navigating to my main composable screen and coming back to the screen with random number generator it does not give me a new sequence of numbers and its the same. so navigating back to the main screen should not work as closing and reopening.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks for all the help it seems to be working for the generating sequences with putting it on an event and all is good. thanks again for the help. you can post the answer if you want so i can give you the upvotes and tag it as an answer <3